# using generic GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a new model to my current setup that will look like this

```
class Cinerama(models.Model):
    memeber = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    #somethins
```

but problem is i don't have a person model i have a boy and girl model like so

```
class Girls(models.Model):
    #somethins only girls do
    #many other fk
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

class Boys(models.Model):
    #somethins only boys do
    #many other fk
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

so i do not want to change the set up around so i want to add tags to both girls and boys then make a new person  model so that the system will look like this

```
class Person(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Cinerama(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    #somethins

class Girls(models.Model):
    #somethins
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    tag= models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Boys(models.Model):
    #somethins
    teacher = models.CharField()
    tag= models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

will this be the best option to take  or using generic.GenericForeignKey will be better and how will u retrieve all students that was taken to the Cinerama by a teacher with a pk=1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic foreign key is required here. Their are other alternaives also e.g. create a person model and extend your boys and girls model from it. A generic relation can be created as:

```
class Cinerama(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    # other fields here
```

Also add a reverse relation in your girl and boy model so that you can do `Girls.cinerama.all()`:

```
class Girls(models.Model):
    cinerama = generic.GenericRelation(Cinerama)
    # other fields here
```

Comment: Aamir i dont quit get this retrieve all students that was taken to the Cinerama by a teacher with a pk=1 or name = 'Aamiee'

Comment: You can filter by teacher id as `Girls.cinerama.filter(teacher_id=1)` i am assuming you have teacher foreign key in `Cinerama` model.

Comment: no teacher has no relation i want to get sudent that came to the cinimer with teacher id =1

Comment: i want something along this line Cinerama.objects.filter(member__teacher__id = 1) so ill get angobject boy or girl

Comment: try this `Cinerama.objects.filter(content_object__teacher__id=1)`